# Resell or Refund the tokens after the ICO ends

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ico, crowdsale

I have 2 questions about ICO:

1.What are the available methods to resell the tokens after the ICO ends?

2.Can the user return the tokens after the ICO ends and get a refund? For example they buy X token for 1 BTC. Can the users can get back the 1 BTC after the ICO ends if they regret their decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will vary by ICOs.

For question 1, you can sell the token off-the-counter. They will often have slack channel or some other form of community, and there might be someone looking for tokens. Alternatively, the token might be able to be traded on some exchanges (e.g. [EOS](https://eos.io/))

For question 2, it will vary by the token being sold, but generally you wouldn't be able to get refund. They will have an in-depth description of selling plan, so you should carefully read the documents.

Comment: How the token would get price increase and how the buyer will get profit if we don't resell it on exchange?

Comment: That's the risk you're taking for participating in the ICO. And the project can suddenly vanish, too. So you should research the project and the investment plan thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't resell ICO tokens. You invested in the ICO because you believe in the product.. right?

Joking aside.

- No you can not get a refund. Why would the project developers offer refunds?
- You can exchange tokens using tools like [EtherDelta](https://etherdelta.github.io).